# Is Orfeo Toolbox OTB no longer available through OSGeo4W?

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, otb-applications

When I run the current OSGeo4W installer on Windows 10, 64 bit, no OTB packages are available:

[image]

The [OTB binary package status page](https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Binary_packages_status#OSGeo4W) still lists OSGeo4W as a source for OTB.

~~Does anyone know what is going on here? Is OTB not distributed via OSGeo4W anymore? Or temporarily unavailable?~~

EDIT:

I just discovered the "Hide obsolete packages" checkbox.

[image]

So why are OTB packages considered obsolete in OSGeo4W?

Comment: I believe that OTB maintainers wanted people to download the official OTB windows install directly from their website, instead of via osgeo4w.

Comment: Also, I think it also has to do with the fact there is no QGIS 3.0 support at the moment

Comment: the technical reason why OTB is not available in osgeo4w is an incompatibility between otb, ossim and geos(see https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/473). Hope that we'll be able to find a solution in the future. In the meantime, I advise to use to use the binary package from the OTB website.